# How to solve the problem with streams in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a problem with streams in python. when I run a script with more than 350 threads, it gives me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 1487, in <module>
    uagents, referers, proxies).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

saw a solution for ubuntu, it consists in changing the configs of the systemd package. But I never figured out how to do it.

Comment: Could you also include the code that each thread executes?

Comment: Why do you have 350 threads...?

Comment: code is very big, i can't send him in post

Comment: idk why my vds have only 350 threads